# Displaying AJAX data in a graph

Tags: ajax, google-visualization, fusioncharts

I wanted to display the data coming from a webservice in graph. I would like to have hours(1-24) on x-axis and only 0&1 values on y-axis. Now if I say 9.15-9.30, the value is 1; how can I display it in graph?

I want to use Fusion Charts or Google Charts.

Comment: post the code what you tried until now.

Comment: I am trying to use win/Los graphs from fusion charts. I didnt understand how to pass data to that graph.

Comment: post your code, so i can help you.

Comment: To use Win/Loss charts, pass the data as W/L/D.  For example Win can depicted for 1.                                                     Set value can be of 3 types:
W - Indicating a win
L - Indicating a loss
D - Indicating a draw. Refer more detailed format at: http://docs.fusioncharts.com/tutorial-attr-sparkwl.html

Answer (score 0):

To pass the data to a Win-Loss chart in FusionCharts, you can use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/5sP8q/). In this fiddle, W represents a win ( in your case its a 1) and L represents a Loss ( in your case its a 0)
http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/5sP8q/

Let me know if this answer helps.

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var salesTarget = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'sparkwinloss',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '350',
        height: '50',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "On-target sales by month",
                "subcaption": "Last year",
                "numberPrefix": "$",
                "chartTopMargin": "10",
                "chartBottomMargin": "10",
                "chartRightMargin": "10",
                "showBorder": "0",
                "bgColor": "#ffffff",                                
                "winColor": "#1aaf5d",
                "lossColor": "#8e0000",
                "showHoverEffect": "1",
                "canvasBorderThickness": "0"
            },
            "dataset": [
                {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "value": "W"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "W"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "W"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "L"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "W"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "W"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "L"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "L"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "W"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "L"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "W"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "W"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    })
    .render();
});
```